# Uploadprogress in Ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, user-experience

I have a form in which user can add information and add images. The images are base64 encoded so everything is stored in a json object.  This object is sent to the server (with `$resource`) when the user submits it.

If a user adds for example 3 Images with about 2MB per Image, has a shitty connection like Edge, and wants to upload it it seems like it's taking forever. The user just sees the `$ionicLoading` overlay without information how long it will take or how much % are already uploaded.

The UX is bad because the user could assume, that the app froze or is in an endless loop and that it's just a bad app.

I have the following ideas but no idea if they are possible or

1. Is there a way in angular, cordova or ionic to get the browserinformation how much % are already uploaded?
2. Is there a way to get the current uploadspeed?  I could get the size of my object by getting the `length` of my  `stringified` JSON Object, divide it 1024 to get the kB. Then i would check the current uploadSpeed every second and add the current uploadspeed to a variable. With this information i could calculate the uploaded % approximately
3. JQuery ajaxForm Plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you are looking for is progress events from [XHR2](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/).

Assuming your server is setup to handle XHR2 and return content-length, In plain JavaScript:

```
function upload(blobOrFile) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/server', true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) { ... };

  // Listen to the upload progress.
  var progressBar = document.querySelector('progress');
  xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
      progressBar.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
      progressBar.textContent = progressBar.value; // Fallback for unsupported browsers.
    }
  };

  xhr.send(blobOrFile);
}

upload(new Blob(['hello world'], {type: 'text/plain'}));
```

Upload speed is also calculable using the information returned in the progress event, as you described.

As for this implementation in AngularJS/Ionic, it seems like this is a longstanding [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1934) within the framework that $http doesn't really support progress events.

I have seen implementations that utilize a special [angular directive](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) written for this, or even utilize a [jQuery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) implementation.

Comment: Works very nice! Combined it with $q.defer() and resolved it when the xhr.onreadystatechange status changed to 4 event so i had to change hardly anything in my code.
 Thanks